# How to handle logging in cross-browser testing in Protractor?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, log4js-node

I was building an automation framework with javascript(VanillaJS), jasmine, and protractor. I chose the log4js with log4js-protractor-appender for the logging. I try to save logs(by browser type) when I perform cross-browser testing. I wanted to run the specs on safari and chrome then expecting to have 2 separate log files for each browser.

Q: How to create two separate log files where one of them contains only log of chrome, the second file contains only logs of safari browser by using technologies mentioned before?

Here is the log4js code from the conf.js file

```
beforeLaunch : function(){
log4js.configure({
        appenders: {
          out: { type: 'console' },
          result: { type: 'dateFile', filename: 'logs/result',"pattern":"-dd.log", alwaysIncludePattern:true}, 
          error: { type: 'dateFile', filename: 'logs/error', "pattern":"-dd.log", alwaysIncludePattern:true}, 
          default: { type: 'dateFile', filename: 'logs/default', "pattern":"-dd.log", alwaysIncludePattern:true}
        },
        categories: {
          default: { appenders: ['out','default'], level: 'info' },
          result: { appenders: ['result'], level: 'info' },
          error: { appenders: ['error'], level: 'error' }
        }
      });
},

onPrepare : function() {
browser.logger = log4js.getLogger('protractorLog4js');
}
```

The expected result is to have 2 files: default_chrome.log & default_safari.log

```
// obtain browser name
    browser.getBrowserName = function() {
        return browser.getCapabilities().then((caps) => {
            browser.browserName = caps.get('browserName');
        }
    )}
    // resolve the promised so the browser name is obtained.
    browser.getBrowserName();
    
    log4js.configure({
      appenders: {
        out: { type: 'console' }, 
        default: { type: 'dateFile', filename: 'logs/default_'+ browser.browserName, "pattern":".log", alwaysIncludePattern:true}
      },
      categories: {
        default: { appenders: ['out','default'], level: 'info' }
      }
    });
```

I tried this option too:

```
var browName = () => {return browser.getCapabilities().then((caps) => {caps.get('browserName');});}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a ready-to-use answer, because it'll require to have your setup locally, but I can give you directions to look in...

According to https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts, `beforeLaunch` is called once per execution (once for all browsers), whereas `onPrepare` is called for each browser instance and should be used for configuring your logger. So everything related to logger should go to `onPrepare`

Comment: if that didn't help, let me know, I'll try to configure this loggrer locally

Comment: Thanks for the response. I put all log conf to ```onPrepare``` but I guess here I'm having a problem with getting the browser name(=> undefined). I would be really thankful if you can write a small portion of the conf file. I updated the last portion of the question

Comment: @OrozbekAskarov use `browser.getProcessedConfig()` instead. The object returned from `.getCapabilities()` isn't in the format you think it is. Something like this should work: `return browser.getProcessedConfig().then(conf => conf.capabilities.browserName)`